# Completion of $\mathbb{E}$ by $\mathbb{N}_\mu$ regarding Lebesgue measure - are my arguments valid

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have the measure space $(X,\mathbb{E},\mu)$ where $\mathbb{E}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I have that 
$$\mathbb{N}_\mu=\{E\subseteq X\; |\; \text{there exist }E\in\mathbb{E}\;\text{so}\;N\subseteq E\;\;\text{and}\;\mu(E)=0\}\in\mathbb{N}_\mu\},$$
so is the following argumentation valid:

The enlargement of $\mathbb{E}$ with respect to $\mu$ is:
$$\mathbb{E}_\mu=\mathbb{E}\cup\mathbb{N}_\mu,$$
so
$$\mathbb{E}\subseteq \mathbb{E}_\mu\quad\quad\text{and}\quad\quad\mathbb{N}_\mu\subseteq \mathbb{E}_\mu$$
as 
$\mathbb{E}=\mathbb{E}_\mu$ \ $\{\mathbb{N}_\mu\}$ and $\mathbb{N}_\mu=\mathbb{E}_\mu$ \ $\{\mathbb{E}\}$.

Comment: I misunderstood what you did, yes this is basically correct.

Comment: Except there are some places where you are sloppy...for example you really want to add sets $B$ such that there is a measurable set $A$ and a measurable set $C$ with $\mu(C)=0$ and $B \setminus A \subseteq C$.

Comment: your definition of $\Bbb N_\mu$ seems wrong. I guess that $\Bbb N_\mu$ want to mean the collection of subsets of any subset of the original $\sigma$-algebra of measure zero. If this is the case you must write in the definition $E\subseteq N$ instead of $N\subseteq E$

Comment: there are some more typos, but the assertions are fine besides that. You want to write $\Bbb E_\mu\setminus\Bbb N_\mu$ and $\Bbb E_\mu\setminus\Bbb E$ instead of what you wrote

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you start with $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$, the completed $\sigma$-algebra is

$$\mathcal{M}^*=\{ B \subseteq X : \text{ there exists } A,C \in \mathcal{M} \: \mu(C)=0 \wedge B \setminus A \subseteq C \}.$$

Note that fixing $C=\emptyset$ inside that set builder reproduces $\mathcal{M}$ itself, so no union is required. Similarly fixing $A=\emptyset$ reproduces all of the actual null sets in the completed space.

This is not quite what you wrote, what you wrote has some minor errors that make it rather nonsensical (for example $E$ being bound under two different quantifiers in the same expression).